# connectedScenes and UIWindowScene to support IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this iOS app which trying to downgrade to support older iPhones with iOS version 11.0, but ran into few problems.

I have the below line of code in `AppDelegate` which shows error `'connectedScenes' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer` and `'UIWindowScene' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer`

```
var keyWindowDev = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive}).map({$0 as? UIWindowScene}).compactMap({$0}).first?.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UIWindowSceneDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,MessagingDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    //....
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
      guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
   }
}

//Below is keyWindowDev usage in AppDelegate

extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = keyWindowDev?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

And `keyWindowDev` is also used to set `SVProgressHUD` Container View around the app

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController{
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       SVProgressHUD.setContainerView(keyWindowDev)
   }
}
```

Please how to change the line of code in `keyWindowDev` to support iOS 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
var keyWindowDev: UIWindow? = {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.first?.windows
            .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    } else {
        return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    }
}()
```

I made some optimizations to your original code.